# "No resources found" from kubectl get for remote cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have kubectl configured for a multi-cluster setup involving local Kubernetes that comes with Docker Mac and a remote cluster using Minikube. When I switch context to my remote cluster kubectl can't find any resources like pods or services. Where can I look at logs to find out more? I do see the resources if I run kubectl on the actual remote machine.

When I execute `kubectl version` I get this:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.3", GitCommit:"721bfa751924da8d1680787490c54b9179b1fed0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-02-01T20:00:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

`kubectl get componentstatus` returns:

```
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE              ERROR
scheduler            Healthy   ok                   
controller-manager   Healthy   ok                   
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health": "true"}
```

`kubectl cluster-info` returns:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://remote-cluster-ip:8443
KubeDNS is running at https://remote-cluster-ip:8443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
```

Executing `kubectl cluster-info dump` produces a ton of output.

I followed these steps to get Minikube working and successfully deployed a sample app.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/

I followed these steps for multi-cluster config:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/

I copied over all the crt and key files from .minikube to my local machine for use in the config. Here is my redacted config:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://localhost:6443
  name: docker-for-desktop-cluster
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://remote-cluster-ip:8443
  name: remote-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-for-desktop-cluster
    user: docker-for-desktop
  name: docker-for-desktop
- context:
    cluster: remote-cluster
    namespace: remote-cluster
    user: minikube
  name: remote-cluster
current-context: remote-cluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: docker-for-desktop
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /path/to/local/client.crt
    client-key: /path/to/local/client.key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to check if you can see pods across all namespaces. 
If you see your pods are running, than you have to set up a default namespace for your current context, i.e.

```
kubectl config set-context <remote-context-name> --namespace=default
```

Comment: Any idea how this can be done on a headless CentOS system? That's where I have Minikube running. I'm using the 'none' VM driver, which means it's using Docker, not a VM. I see quite a few k8s-related containers running.

Comment: Also, if I needed to forward a port to begin with, how am I able to connect using `kubectl cluster-info`?

Comment: @GabeV First of all check if port forwarding is allowed at all - `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding` if returns 0, than enable by `sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding=1` And then `sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 6443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
`

Comment: Looks like forwarding is already enabled. I don't think I need to do anything with iptables since I can connect to the cluster already right? I just can't discover the resources.

Comment: @GabeV sounds reasonable.  Let's start from the very bottom. Can you please switch to your remote context and share the output of the command `kubectl cluster-info -v99`

Comment: it produces a lot of output, including some stuff I might need to obfuscate since it's a corporate system. Anything in particular I should look for? I don't think I can add a file here can I?

Comment: Basically, we need to insure that kubctl send a proper API request and receives valid response from API server.  So if you run `kubectl get pods -v9` you should see a response as follows: `I0322 09:47:56.380464  167499 request.go:874] Response Body: {"kind":"PodList","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods","resourceVersion":"1868491"},"items":[{"metadata":{"name":"foobar","namespace":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/foobar","uid":"c2f0ab9f-4be9-11e9-9c16-42010a9c0010","resourceVersion":"1726621"` and so on listing all pods properties

Comment: Btw, if you if do `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` you still don't see anything ?

Comment: Looks like --all-namespaces works. I can see my pod plus the k8s pods since I'm using vm-driver=none. This is interesting. Without `all-namespaces`, it's defaulting to the name of my context instead of 'default'. I can see now I'm using that in the config. I changed the namespace to `default` and it works. Thanks! If you want some credit please put that as an answer.

Comment: @GabeV happy it helped. I've updated my answer accordingly.  Thnx